# Is it possible to see all the file changes for a particular file in Subversion that relate to a given issue number?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

For example I have a file 'Example.cs' and I want to see all changes made to this file between revision 800 and 1200. However comparing these two revisions will also show changes I'm not interested in as I just want to see the code changes that relate to a specific issue number entered when making commits on that file.

Is there a way to view these using Subversion/TortoiseSVN?

Comment: When you `Show Log` on Tortoise SVN, you can enter the Issue Number (I'm hoping you've entered it in comments section). Another Way - Right Click - Tortiose SVN - Blame. Else, please elaborate the question

Comment: What's the "specific issue number"? How do you enter it? As a comment? As custom svn property?

Comment: OK, a better way of phrasing the question would be that I'd like to compare two revisions of the file (say 1200 to 800) but I only want to see changes that have been made on specific check-ins (not all other changes to the file which are unrelated to what I want to see). Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

When selecting Blame, enter the revision numbers you want to compare but on my version of TortioseSVN there's a tick box towards the bottom called "Use text viewer to view blames". This will open up the blame file in your local text viewer.

The columns are delimited with a space so you can easily open this up in MS Excel and sort the data into columns.

Finally add a filter to each of the columns and on the Revision column you can just tick all the revisions you want to see the changes for

Answer (score 0):

Bash script to the rescue:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=file
ISSUE="#12"


for rev in $(svn log ${FILE} | grep ^r[0-9] | sed 's/r\([0-9]*\)\ .*/\1/g')
do
  svn log -r${rev} | tail -n +3 | head -n -1 | grep "${ISSUE}" > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    svn diff ${FILE} -c${rev}
  fi
done
```

The script above searchs the log of the file FILE, present in the working copy, looking for the string ISSUE in the commit message and prints the diff of that revision to the command line.